D365FO x++ Present Value function like PV function in excel
I need to calculate present value of given value and interest rate. In excel there is a function PV(), the same result I have to calculate using x++. Please suggest the solution, I have tried to find the function but in vain.
Thanks

You could try the pv function in X++.
It is dcumented here.
